# Android google maps v2 cluster markers if they are close to each other

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer

I have an app which uses google maps and places markers on it. The problem is, that I don't know at the runtime the coordinates of the markers. So my question is, is there any library that is capable of clustering my markers if they are close by and after zooming in disperse them in their proper location ? Possibly also when clicking the cluster showing it's content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is. There is an official Map Utils library: http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/

It does a lot of stuff actually:

- Items clustering
- custom icons generation
- polylines decoding/encoding
- heatmaps
- spherical geometry

Feel free to check out clustering example: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/ClusteringDemoActivity.java